# How to extract variable-number elements list from a tibble cell?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an unseen use-case :) I have the following list of movie genre combinations:

```
test <- c("Comedy|Romance", 
          "Action|Crime|Thriller", 
          "Action|Adventure|Drama|Sci-Fi")
```

I worked out tokenizing each element into a list as follows:

```
res <- sapply(test, function(x) {
    unlist(strsplit(x, "\\|"))
})
tibble::enframe(res)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
name                            value    
<chr>                           <list>   
1 Comedy|Romance                <chr [2]>
2 Action|Crime|Thriller         <chr [3]>
3 Action|Adventure|Drama|Sci-Fi <chr [4]>
```

But then I end up with variable-number vector elements in the value cell that I don't know how to extract into a single vector. How can we extract those list elements into a unique final result?

```
final
[1] "Action" "Adventure" "Comedy" "Crime" "Drama" "Romance" "Sci-Fi" "Thriller"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `test` you can do:

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(test, "\\|")))
```

Or from your tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble::enframe(res)

df %>%
  pull(value) %>%
  flatten_chr() %>%
  unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

A different option starting from the tibble is to use `unnest`:

```
tibble::enframe(res) %>% unnest(value) %>% pull(value) %>% unique
```